# Selectively get email messsages with Gmail API

Tags: python, email, google-api, gmail, gmail-api

I am trying to grab a list of messages that have a specific content e.g. billing emails and work on data in there. 
In order to get these messages, I run the following

```
service.users().messages().list(userId=user_id, page_token=page_token, q=query).execute()
```

which returns all the messages. 
I want to limit the messages that I get to confirm to the following criteria:

- Sent in the last two days
- Definitely deny if `from:` address not in a list of email addresses i.e. blacklist e.g. notifications, facebook
- Definitely accept if `from:` address in a list of email addresses i.e. whitelist
- Look if the `subject:` matches a set of strings

I understand that I can create a query that would match the email address and subject (`from:bill@pge.com AND subject:"Your bill for this month"`), but the blacklist and whitelist, as mentioned above, can become significantly large as the scope  and the number of vendors I can accept increases, and similar is the case with subject. So my question is:

- Is there a limit on the number of query terms?
- Is there a way to achieve this other than generating a very long query string combining the black list whitelist and subject (`from:abc@this.com AND NOT from:xyz@that.com AND subject:"Your bill" AND subject:"This month's bill"`)?

Note: For project settings I mostly conform to https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no limit documented for the number of query terms you can use. Yes, you would have to create programmatically a long query string combining all the emails from the lists. Here [1] you can check the operators you can use, the best approach would be like this:

1) Use "after" or "newer" operators with a timestamp from 2 days before the current date.

2) -from:{xxx@xxx.com xxx@xxx.com ...}

3) from:{xxx@xxx.com xxx@xxx.com ...}

4) subject:{xxx xxx ...}

[1] https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190